# vue3, vite and vue-router@next, cannot resolve component router-view

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, vue-router4

I created a project using Vite and added vue-router@next. I am using the router inside of the main.js as I've browsed around and seemed like this was the problem, however it does not fix the issue I am having.

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "rng-alpha",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.0.5",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^1.1.5",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.7",
    "vite": "^2.0.5"
  }
}

// main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router/router';

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(router);
app.mount('#app');

// router.js
import {
  createWebHistory,
  createRouter
} from 'vue-router'

import Home from '../components/Home.vue'

const routes = [{
  path: "/",
  name: "Home",
  component: Home
}]

const router = createRouter[{
  history: createWebHistory,
  routes,
}]

export default router

// App.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <div>hi</div>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>
```

The warnings I am getting are the following:
[image]

How can I make the router-view work? Since I am not able to utilize it right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`createRouter` is a method that should be called using `()` not `[]` :

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory,
  routes,
})
```